# Display nested field groups in a custom content type in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck

Is it possible to have nested groups in a custom content type in Drupal? I want to achieve the following in the 'Manage fields' page:

```
+ Tab Group 1
    + field_some_text_1
    + field_some_text_2
    + Standard Group 1
        + field_some_text_3
        + field_some_text_4
    + field_some_text_5
    + Standard Group 2
        + field_some_text_6
        + field_some_text_7
 + Tab Group 2
    + etc...
```

The `Tab Groups` would then ideally contain other standard groups which will make CSS based layout a little easier.

Some discussions around this exist on the Drupal forums (see for example [here](http://drupal.org/node/108753), [here](http://drupal.org/node/300084?page=1) and [here](http://drupal.org/node/849420)).

Does anyone know if this is doable in Drupal? I am on Drupal Core 6.19 and CCK 6.x-2.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've wanted to do something similar, but unfortunately, as you can tell with all of the discussions going on, it's not possible right now.  They way the field groups are structured, it would require quite a re-write of the functionality, and no one has taken up the task for that yet.  So... sorry. (I would love to have it too though!)

Answer (score 0):

The best solutions are unfortunately work-arounds based on panels and views.